# PWA to TWA Issue - Android launcherName displays as 'Chrome' instead of the expected name, but it shows fine in other views

Tags: android, progressive-web-apps, trusted-web-activity, pwabuilder

#### What happened?

I have generated a PWA application with source code on the website. My PWA configuration is passed on the website; however, the TWA generated doesn't show the right name. The application's name works fine in the app list and settings, except for this area.

**Preview:**
[image]

#### How can you reproduce the behavior?

1. Go to pwabuilder.com and insert your PWA url website
2. Package for Stores
3. Find 'Android' and select Generate Package
4. Fill out the configuration more important is App name, version, manifest location, my current fallback behavior is Custom Tabs and display mode is set to standalone, enable Include source code and disable Signing key since i dont want to upload my key
5. Download package
6. Open the source code with Android Studio
7. Generate the Signed file upload to Google Play

#### What do I expect to happen?

I haven't really touched anything in this source code yet. The reason I downloaded it is just in case I want to change or update the notification settings and also for APK signing before uploading it to the Google Play Store.

What I expect to happen is for the name of my app to show up when navigating to that area, not only on the app settings page or app list, as users may get confused with this issue.

[image]

#### What environment were i'm using?

- **OS:** Android 13
- **Browser:** Chrome
- **Version:** 115.0.5790.138

#### Additional context

**Note:** Digital Assets Link key and from Google play store is already added to my asset link json file, Been using this PWA since 2019 and this is the first time I encounter this problem.

Via Github: [[BUG] Android launcherName is Chrome #4227](https://github.com/pwa-builder/PWABuilder/issues/4227)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This issue is already moved at:**

[Issue 1472686: [BUG] PWA to TWA Implementation - Android launcherName is Chrome](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1472686#c_ts1692011995).

**Based on peconn:**
Unfortunately this is a bug on Android's side - we call Activity#setTaskDescription in order for that text to be your PWA's, but from Android P onward this doesn't take effect. There's no more we can do.

(For future Googler's looking at this issue, the Android bug is b/161535338, but that won't be accessible to the public.)

[Read More..](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1472686#c_ts1692011995)